# Устанавливать фокус на TextEdit и ввод с клавиатуры при любых нажатий кнопок из другой формы C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

имеется 3 формы MainForm(), Form1(MainForm()), Form2(),в Form 1 передаётся MainForm через конструктор, мне нужно обновить TextEdit Form1() из Form2(). Я сделал пустой контруктор Form1 который не принимает не какие параметры, нужно постаянно ставить фокус на textEdit, при запуске приложения, при взаимодействии с кнопками из другой формы

В коде выглядит это так:
в Form1():

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Testi();
    }

    public void Testi()
    {
        this.searchTextEdit.Text = "";
        this.searchTextEdit.Focus();
        
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста правильно поставить фокус в TextEdit из Form2() при вызове в Form1(), спасибо.

Form2:

```
  Form2()
   {
        Form1 test = new Form1;
        Action showMethod = test.Testi;
        showMethod();
    }
```

Попробовал сделать через делегать Action но проблема в том что фокус всё-равно не ставиться в поле ввода

Comment: Также как в Form1 передаётся MainForm, нужно в Form2 передавать Form1.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Обновил вопрос

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я просто немного недопонимаю как работать с объектами и их событиями из другой формы

Comment: Мне нужно просто организовать фокус на textEdit при любых обстоятельствах, будто нажатие кнопки и т.д. помогите пожалуйста кто знает разобраться

Comment: А куда делся вызов `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: @aepot Да я упустил, но уже добавил, проблема с исключением исчезла, а вот проблем с возвратом фокуса на textEdit осталась, просто не реагирует (( Не понимаю как заставить фокус постоянно держать на textEdit из любой формы

Comment: Обновите вопрос, исправьте код и сведения о проблеме.

Comment: @aepot обновил. Спасибо

Comment: Код, показанный в вопросе, не скомпилируется, применение модификаторов доступа недопустимо для методов, которые вложены в другие методы, в данном случае конструктор класса, но так как об этой проблеме вы не сообщаете, делаю вывод, что показанный код не соответствует действительности.

Comment: @aepot поправил

Comment: С кодом Form2 тоже что-то не то 1) InitializeComponent пропал, 2) модификатор доступа конструктора отсутствует (так задумано?)

Comment: `Form1(MainForm())` говорите про то что есть аргумент, а в коде - нет. Описание не соответствует показанному коду. Приведите вопрос в порядок, пожалуйста.

Comment: Далее, даже если случится так, что вы причешете несоответствия в вопросе, то не совсем понятно, а что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать с этим фокусом, какая задача решается, зачем вам вообще фокус? Зачем вам что-то обновлять из одной формы в другой, ведь каждая форма должна отвечать только за свой собственный внешний вид, иначе будет каша, а вы будете умирать над кодом, переставая понимать, как его дорабатывать и исправлять ошибки. Чтобы дать вменяемый ответ, надо понимать, а что вообще происходит. Быть может вам не нужен фокус? Быть может я зануда, но я не хочу в угадайку с ответом играть.

Comment: @aepot Вы не зануда, просто я наверное слишком мало даю информации либо не могу правильно сформулировать свой вопрос, это нормально на этапе обучения (наверное). Суть такова что в поле происходит ввод данных потом нажимается кнопка ОК либо ТЕСТ. При нажатии ОК всплывает диалоговое окно с кнопками "да" и "нет" при нажатии которых мне нужно что бы в поле TextEdit можно было вводить данные с клавиатуры без кликанья туда мышкой так как фокус после всплывающего диалога теряется и с клавиатуры ввода не происходит пока не кликнишь на поле ввода

Comment: У меня 2 конструктора 1 принимает параметры, второй я сделал без параметров

Comment: Ну вот, так гораздо понятнее, ответ будет очень простой, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Суть такова что в поле происходит ввод данных потом нажимается кнопка ОК либо ТЕСТ. При нажатии ОК всплывает диалоговое окно с кнопками "да" и "нет" при нажатии которых мне нужно что бы в поле TextEdit можно было вводить данные с клавиатуры без кликанья туда мышкой

Вам нужно просто вернуть фокус в поле ввода после вызова диалога.

Уберите все костыли из второй формы.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Вот так, все должно стать чисто.

Теперь в методе вызова второй формы-диалога есть код, который вы не показали, но я его попробую придумать сам.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) // вы же кнопкам этом диалоге назначили DialogResult в дизайнере формы, верно?
                                                   // если нет, разберитесь как оно работает, очень полезная штука
    {
        // ...
    }
    searchTextEdit.Focus();
}
```

Вот и вся магия.

Comment: спасибо за ответ и Ваше терпение, хорошего Вам дня

Comment: @Ethernets еще нюанс: Не пишите свой код в конструкторе окна, используйте обработчик события `Form.Load` (появляется в коде при двойном клике на саму форму в дизайнере формы). В конструкторе допускается только запись полученных в аргументы данных в поля или свойства класса. Конструктор должен выполняться максимально быстро и не должен содержать кода, способного вызвать исключение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за хороший совет и подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Самое очевидное решение - передавать ссылку на метод (делегат) в конструктор формы. Советую почитать - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.13.php.

Так же, как вариант, можно забить на все эти сложности и воспользоваться готовыми делегатами Action или Func. Ссылка - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.33.php.

Таким образом, вы передаёте ссылку на метод в качестве параметра в конструктор и вызываете её в нужный момент.

Как по мне, передавать всю форму является не совсем правильным, т.к. это уже отдельный объект, который, как мне кажется, должен быть максимально изолированным от другой формы

UPD:

public void GetSomething(Action action, string YYY) => action.Invoke(YYY);

Данный метод GetSomething принимает в себя void-метод, в качестве параметра к которому нужно передать string.

public int ReturnSomething(Func<string, int> func, string YYY) => func.Invoke(YYY);

Данный метод ReturnSomething принимает в себя метод, который возвращает int и принимает в качестве параметра string.

Таким образом, вам нужно в конструкторе указать Func или Action и передавать их. Вызывать с помощью Invoke().

Comment: Попробовал через делегат Action но без результата, выше приложил кусок кода, как это делал я

Comment: @Ethernets Обновил. Проверьте и отпишите, помогло или нет. Если нет, тегните меня с помощью "@"

Comment: В комментах под постом автора тегать автора поста не нужно, он в любом случае получит уведомление. Ну как вы сейчас получили уведомление об этом комментарии. Тегать надо тогда, когда коммент обращен не к автору поста.

Comment: _Вызывать с помощью Invoke()._ - `action()` и `action.Invoke()` это синтаксически эквивалентные записи. С другой стороны я вообще не уверен, что автору помогут делегаты, так как вопрос не про них. Плюс они добавляют еще один уровень сложности приложению, как минимум потому что автор пока не может справиться и без них. Вы же согласитесь, что делегаты всего-лишь добавляют гибкости в решениях, а не простоты в реализации? В общем, мне кажется, что есть решение попроще. Осталось только узнать у автора, а что же он на самом деле хочет сделать, а не играть в угадайку.